# Ninja Trader Coded Strategy not working as intended

Tags: c#, algorithmic-trading, ninjatrader

I am making a mechanical counter-trend strategy for trading futures contracts. The strategy uses the MBox Algo indicator, filtering for Springs and Upthrusts in a counter-trend direction, to identify potential trades.
These are the rules
Use the MBox Algo indicator and filter for Springs and Upthrusts in a counter-trend direction.
Enter trades when the price breaks the previous swing high or low.
Exit trades at a 1:1 risk-reward ratio.
Only trade between 9:30 AM and 12:00 PM.
​ The issue is It fires multiple trades, where it shouldn't.

The MBoxUpthrust is the original file that was working fine
It isnt until I pasted it in a blank strategy template (with stops, time zones etc) that it stopped working properly.
So I think I could be in trade management, but I'm not sure.​
The AlgoMbox is the new file

Could someone please help me out to find whats the bug in the new file thats causing it. Thanks[drive link with the cs files in it](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-mGcWt5UoSwaOY4UPZFytdrwD0YcCe5r?usp=sharing)

Tried Running it and it fired multiple trades

Comment: Please post the relevant pieces of code as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) text in your question instead of linking to a random google drive with some code. I also recommend taking the [tour]